# linker script conditional includes

Tags: c++, c, linker, arm, ld

I am converting a scatter file to linker file. Now the problem is armlink can accept symbols e.g `--predefine=-DSOME_VARIABLE` at link time and in the scatter file other header files can be included with the `#include "someHeader.h` directive. There are files which are included in scatter file on the bases of defined symbols e.g

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_RANDOM_FILE 
    randomFile (*) 
#endif
```

in linker script these options are not available. is there a work around for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two fairly simple options.

1. Use a compiler pre-processor and use the output.
2. Invert your logic.

---

Use the C pre-processor in GCC or any compiler.

```
 $(CC) $(DEFINES) -E -P -o output.lds -x c-header input.lds
```

This option allows the full range of pre-processor defines and conditional inclusion.

---

The *invert* option is to have separate master 'lds' files for each case you need and then include the common portion.

**flash.lds**

```
start = 0xf000000;
size  = 0x100000;
include "common.lds"
```

**ram.lds**

```
start = 0x0;
size  = 0x10000;
include "common.lds"
```

The same can be **production** and **debug** variants.  This is fairly easy if the permutations are low.  Otherwise, I would use the pre-processing.

The [bin-utils ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/REGION_005fALIAS.html) also has a good example with a *linkcmds.memory* file.  You would have to *symlink* or copy the *linkcmds.memory* file in your `Makefile` or build process.

---

It is often surprisingly easy to get rid of the conditions by using `weak` symbols and stub file and routines that make conditions unneeded.

Comment: Preprocessing can lead to obscure failures when globbed filenames are involved in the linker script:

`*(EXCLUDE_FILE(*/foo/* hello.o */bar))` has those /* */ parsed as comment and discarded.

That can be worked around (cpp -C), but if there's a larger region covered by such an unexpected 'comment', any symbols and preprocessing rules within it still aren't processed.

Comment: That would be odd as the [GNU LD says it accepts C comments](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Script-Format.html#Script-Format); they must special case parsing of **EXCLUDE_FILE**.

Comment: It looks like they consider EXCLUDE_FILE() contents to be a string. The work-around I found is to make them strings: EXCLUDE_FILE("*/foo/*" "hello.c" "*/bar") works and is cpp-safe.